# How to export and cite Google Ngram Viewer result?

Tags: citations, graphics, latex

I am working on a paper (written in LaTeX) and want to include [this result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=microgrid%2Celectric+grid%2C+micro-grid&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmicrogrid%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectric%20grid%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmicro%20-%20grid%3B%2Cc0) from Google Ngram Viewer, showing/comparing the frequency of word usage in published books over time:

[image]

What is the proper way to cite this result? and is there a better way of saving the image than taking a screenshot?

It seems the image itself is generated as an **svg** (for, I assume, scaled vector graphic?). This would be a convenient way to save it for use in LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you download this python script https://github.com/econpy/google-ngrams

This allows you to download a .csv file containing the data of your search. Then you can plot with your favourite program in your favourite format to be embedded into latex.

Concerning the .svg, it's perfect for latex, especially if you have Inkscape
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz

Comment: I'll check out the script... for using Inkscape, how would I get the ngram into Inkscape? copy the code section from the page source?

Comment: If you download the .csv with the script, you don't need to produce an .svg to open with Inkscape.

However, if you know a bit of Python, you can produce an .svg of your data with Python.

Comment: One part of the question remains unanswered, though: "What is the proper way to cite the result?" According to https://books.google.com/ngrams/info, you are supposed to cite the original paper by the google books team, but I'm not sure whether that makes sense given that the purpose of a citation is to allow the reader to find the original source.